# typescript-eslint "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I try settup eslint with typescript-eslint. My config from docs:

```
import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended
);
```

In IDE error:

```
import eslint from '@eslint/js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Your tsconfig.json will help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution problem

For eslint/js v8 need use [this doc](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/legacy-eslint-setup/)